# BCP In a utf8 text file to table

Tags: mysql, utf-8, sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq

I'm using SYbase bcp to transfer data from a text file to a database table.

My file is encoded in utf8, and i can get some data in my table, but it is not my original text.

I've tried the following commands to no luck

`bcp schemaname..tablename in filename -c -Y -J -Sserver -Uuser -Ppassword`

`bcp schemaname..tablename in filename -c -Y -Jutf8 -Sserver -Uuser -Ppassword`

`bcp schemaname..tablename in filename -c -Jutf8 -Sserver -Uuser -Ppassword`

My utf8 encoded text file contains:

> der märz

But in my database I see:

> der mÃ€rz

Comment: what is the datatype of the column?

Comment: As mentioned below, what is the sort order of your database? And please don't spam tags.  MySQL is a completely different product from Sybase ASE, which is also completely different from Sybase IQ.  What database are you actually using?

Comment: Mojibake should turn `märz` into `mÃ¤rz`.  Perhaps a secondary thing is converting the "currency symbol" into "euro sign".

Comment: I have transferred utf8(Japanese character) using dbis tool.. https://dbisweb.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think your database server has not utf8 character set, can you verify it by running sp_helpsort?